# avoiding twitter's login prompt with tweetsharp

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

i'm using tweetsharp to allow users to log into my site with their twitter account. the first time through, they need to give permission through twitter to access my site. fine. but this happens after the first time too. is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the issue is that you need to use the `authenticate` method instead of the `authorize` method. the authenticate method will only prompt for authorization once.

Answer (score 2):

When the process completes, you should have an Access Token from Twitter for your user. If you store that, you can use it to authenticate your calls from that point forward unless the user or Twitter itself revokes your applications access for some reason.  You don't need to go through the whole RequestToken/Redirect to web page/AccessToken steps every time.  The Access Token is good forever.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a project at http://ruf.codeplex.com/ that works fine using OAuth and tweetsharp. You can have a look at that.

What i did was to simply store the auth token and secret in cookies. And I check for that so that the user does not have to keep on logging in.